# Fetching One, Two, or Both elements from a joined table while ignoring Nulls

Tags: mysql

categories

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | category1 |
| 2 | category2 |

identifier

| id | identifier |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | alpha |
| 2 | bravo |
| 3 | charlie |

category_identifier

| category_id | identifier_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

I need to query a category given the name of the category and identifiers. Each category row can be any combination of identifiers.

| param1 | param2 |
| --- | --- |
| alpha | bravo |
| alpha | null |
| null | alpha |

I managed to get this query:

```
SELECT category1.category_id FROM
(SELECT CI.category_id FROM CATEGORY_IDENTIFIER CI
    JOIN CATEGORY C on CI.category_id = C.category_id
    JOIN IDENTIFIER I on CI.identifier_id = I.identifier_id
WHERE I.identifier = 'alpha') category1
JOIN
(SELECT CI.category_id FROM CATEGORY_IDENTIFIER CI
    JOIN CATEGORY C on CI.category_id = C.category_id
    JOIN IDENTIFIER I on CI.identifier_id = I.identifier_id
WHERE I.identifier <=> 'bravo') category2
ON category1.category_id = category2.category_id
```

I've experimented with different kinds of joins but I cannot get the query to handle NULLs properly.

Comment: Not sure I follow the desired results. Why can't you just JOIN the three tables?

Comment: @SOS I have a situation where I need two results from the third table and/or/andornull

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't clarify things.  Is the problem that you want to convert the rows into two columns? Can there be more than 2 identifier's per category? If so, what's the maximum number allowed?